# SQL - Filter on the latest date row

Tags: sql, filter, google-bigquery, where-clause

I've got a table as below

| ID | Name | Won? | CloseDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 011 | Forum Renewal | No | 01/08/21 |
| 011 | Forum Renewal | Yes | 01/09/21 |
| 011 | New Business | No | 01/02/22 |
| 012 | CX & FM Renewal | Yes | 01/03/21 |
| 012 | CX & FM Renewal | No | 01/08/22 |

I want to be able to pull out only the Renewal lines but only if it doesn't have another Renewal line with the same ID on a date after it. So the above example would pull nothing through for 011 but something for 022

I've got the below code but no idea where to bring in the filter

```
where 
SO1.CloseDate > '2021-01-01'
and (SRT.Name = 'Forum Renewal' OR SRT.Name = 'CX & FM Renewal')
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM SRT T1
WHERE (T1.Name = 'Forum Renewal' OR T1.Name = 'CX & FM Renewal')
AND T1.CloseDate = (
    SELECT MAX(T2.CloseDate)
    FROM SRT T2
    WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
    AND (T2.Name = 'Forum Renewal' OR T2.Name = 'CX & FM Renewal')
    )
```